# How to idnetify which receipt belongs to which user

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, uniqueidentifier

I am doing one application.In that i am storing the receipts in server side.But whenever i try to store on server i need unique identification for each user receipt.So is there any unique value come in apple server response when we send the receipt to apple for validation.Or is there any option to uniquly identify the each user receipt.

Comment: If you want to identify each "user device" (may be shared by many users and one user may have many devices), you could use the device UUID from the app delegate - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken

Comment: Is it accepted by apple.From which verision onwards it's available.May be this is from ios 7 onwards.But i need my app to run from ios 5 onwards.

Comment: Yup. But the device has to register to receive push notifications. You can do that in the appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Is it working in ios5 onwards.

Comment: yes, it does work in ios5

Comment: With UUID you'll get the a string unique per device. A potential problem would be if you have a user with two or more devices, will get different UUIDs for the same appleID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use advertisingIdentifier member of [ASIdentifierManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ASIdentifierManager) or you can create a UUID (with [NSUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUUID/UUID) class) and store it in user defaults.

This is the recommended "apple" way ... but I think you still have the problem with two devices using the same apple ID.